# Go back to view controller from tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I have a viewController. This view controller goes to a `TabBarViewController` which has two childs. How can I go back from this child(s) to root view controller ? ( I Want to go back to the first view controller after clicking on UPDATE/CHANGE button )

I have tried this but it's not working.

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: what not working mean? what happens? are you using navigation controller?

Comment: I would suggest to show your view controllers hierarchy.

Comment: It's not go back to the root view controller. yes, i am using navigation controller.

Comment: Maybe you are setting the tabbar controller as your rootview controller , as mentioned above a view controller hierarchy would be helpful

Comment: how you go to `TabBarViewController` from `ViewController`? did you set `TabBarViewController` as `rootController` or push like normal ?

Comment: I have attached view controllers hierarchy.

Comment: @Kuldeep - I just push it normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it's working for you.

```
_ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

or

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this flow it's working perfectly for me.

Set a tag Value for each viewcontroller like below image and use the below code inside the button action.

```
@IBAction func ButtonActin(_ sender: Any)
{
   // Button Action from viewcontrollerOne to viewcontrollerZero
   tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

[image]